# Strncmp - wrong logic

Tags: c

While running the code below I see, that  `"x,y"` pattern occurs. This pattern is beeing printed here: `printf("%s", start);`. But  `if (strncmp(cp, VAL, strlen(VAL) == 0 ))` is not stepped in. I wouold expect, it should be stepped in.
What is wrong?

```
   me@host ~ $ ./test|grep x,y
   <P k="x,y" v="160.59" z="100"/>
```

This is a part of code:

```
 #define VAL                       "\"x,y\""

void process(char * start, char *stop)
{
  char * cp;
  printf("process\n");
  printf("%s", start);
  for (cp = start; cp <= stop; cp++)
  {
    if (strncmp(cp, VAL, strlen(VAL) == 0 ))
    {
       printf ("F O U N D  VAL\n");
    }
```

}

Comment: Look where your `==` is.

Comment: If you are trying to parse XML, then use an XML parsing library...

Comment: @H2CO3 why would it be better?

Comment: @user897237 because XML parsing libraries are estabilished, well-written, and **working,** and they are suited for parsing XML, unlike `strcmp()` (especially when used incorrectly).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you meant

```
if (strncmp(cp, VAL, strlen(VAL)) == 0)
```

instead that

```
if (strncmp(cp, VAL, strlen(VAL) == 0 ))
```

which basically checks `0` characters, returns `0`, so the condition is always `false`.